# Reference two different schema in joi for date validation

Tags: node.js, joi

I wanted to reference startDate of Projects to startDatePlanned of Milestone to make sure that startDatePlanned is greater than the Project startDate.

But i get the error `references "ref:Project.startDate" which is not a date`

My code is as follows

```
const Project = {
      id: Joi.number().optional(),
      name: Joi.string().required(),
      startDate: Joi.date().required()

    }
    const Phases = Joi.object().keys({
      id: Joi.number().optional(),
      name: Joi.string().required(),
      milestones: Joi.array().items(Milestone).unique()
    });

    const Milestone = Joi.object().keys({
      id: Joi.number().optional(),
      name: Joi.string().required(),
      projectPhaseId: Joi.number().optional(),
      startDatePlanned: Joi.date().required().greater(Joi.ref('Project.startDate')).optional(),
      endDatePlanned: Joi.date().required().greater(Joi.ref('startDatePlanned')).optional(),
      startDateActual: Joi.date().optional().greater(Joi.ref('startDatePlanned')).optional(),
    });
```

Comment: `Joi.ref()` will only work if you're referencing within the same schema. The variable `Project` is completely out of its scope of visibility.